# In scala, why string has ordering but Seq[Char] doesn't?

Tags: scala, sorting

They are pretty much the same thing. Yes, only the first of the following codes can be compiled:

sorting String:

```
val ss = Seq(
  "abc",
  "def"
)

ss.sorted
```

sorted Seq:

```
val ss = Seq(
  "abc",
  "def"
)
.map(_.toSeq)

ss.sorted
```

What's the point of such design?

Comment: If you provide Ordering for Seq[Char], why not for Seq[Int], Seq[Double], Seq[Seq[Seq[Int]]]...?

Comment: @n.m. Indeed, why not?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov nothing wrong with it, it's just a question about ordering of Seq[Char] is odly specific.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add

```
import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits._
```

(or `scala.math.Ordering.Implicits.seqOrdering`).

Why you need this extra import is in the documentation:

> [Not in the standard scope due to the potential for divergence: For instance `implicitly[Ordering[Any]]` diverges in its presence.](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Ordering$$ExtraImplicits.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think that `String` and `Seq[Char]` are isomorphic but not same. They are 'same' in the same way as `Int` and `(Byte, Byte, Byte, Byte)`. `String` has additional semantics.

If you add `Ordering[Seq[Char]]` then it would be consistent to have `Ordering[A : Ordered]`. And it looks quite opinionated to be in stdlib.

Anyways it's not a 'design' problem since nothing stops you from writhing an instance of `Ordering[Seq[Char]]` yourself.

Comment: Except it _is_ in stdlib, just behind an import for technical reasons.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/4494095/9204: "I think it's an oversight. Lexicographic ordering does make sense on Seqs. We should add it to the standard library." (in 2010)